# Application won't navigate to next app page

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation

I am creating an android app, I won't to navigate from "test1" to "test2" but when I press "btnNext" nothing happens.  I am using the same code that I used for other navigations within my app so I don't understand why it won't work.  Can someone help please?

"test1" xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Please Answer the 9 Following Questions"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
    android:text="Depression Test"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtSubTitle"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="59dp"
    android:text="Q.1. Have you found little pleasure or interest in doing things?"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:text="On some days" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:text="No, not at all" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadioButton01"
    android:text="On more than half the days" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/RadioButton03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/RadioButton02"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadioButton02"
    android:text="Nearly every day" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:text="Next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadioButton03"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:text="Next" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

"Test1.java" code:

```
package com.lifematters;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Test1 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test1);

    //define Navigation Image Buttons
    final Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);


  //Set up listener for Test
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //listener call this function
            openTest2();
        }
    });


  }

  //Open test page
    public void openTest2() {
     //create new textview
      Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Test2.class);
      startActivity(i);
   }


 }
```

"Test2.java" code:

```
package com.lifematters;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Test2 extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test2);

    //define Navigation Image Buttons
    final Button nextBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);


  //Set up listener for Test
    nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //listener call this function
            openTest3();
        }
    });


   }

  //Open test page
   public void openTest3() {
     //create new textview
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Test3.class);
    startActivity(i);
  }


}
```

I have declared the activities in the Android Manifest and I am getting zero errors in my log cat.

Comment: where is test2.xml code?

Comment: But in both Java forms I have declared the instance/contentView to the correct form so I'm not sure this will make a difference.  But I will give it a go.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.test2); so you need to get your button names right in both layouts and then call them with respective names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change buttons code in xml to this

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtQ1"
    android:text="Next" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnNext1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/RadioButton03"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txtTitle"
    android:text="Next" />
```

you are having problem because you are calling button with wrong id. check your button id's in test2.xm as well. it will run then

Answer (score 1):

You have two buttons named "btnNext". That's why it doesn't work.
Double check this:

```
"@+id/btnNext"
```

You have the same id set twice...